# Is compulsory to set cookie and secure flag?

Tags: html, wordpress, cookies, http-headers, securesocial

I have website all the files are html and sub directory blog section is wordpress, In complete website there is no user login or signups are there, and we dont even have any cookies.

No my company forcing to add this, I tried all the ways but it doesn't work even in the wordpress.

I have used following codes for wordpress in wp-config

```
 // ** X-Frame-Options Header ** //
header('X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN');

// ** Cookie with HTTPOnly and Secure flag ** //
@ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', true);
@ini_set('session.cookie_secure', true);
@ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', true);
```

Comment: Are trying to show cookie consent banner for users visiting the website.?

Comment: @MujeebuRahman no not at all, is this compulsory?

Comment: For European customers, it's compulsory - Check this plugin [link] https://wordpress.org/plugins/cookie-law-info/

Comment: check this link as well - https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-set-get-and-delete-wordpress-cookies-like-a-pro/